# Android login send JSON with an "api_key" to server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

Hello I'm a newbie develop android. I am trying to learn about login with JSON.
Now my server developer partner ask for me to send a JSON request like below:

```js
{
   "operation":"register",
   "api_key":"123",

   "user":{
        "name":"Wang Jian",
        "email":"wangjian0716@gmail.com",
        "password":"12345678"
   }
}
```

Now i am asked for add "api_key" to matching his server code.
There are code as below Please help me to check whether it would succeed to send a JSON like above.

**ServerRequest.java**

```
public class ServerRequest {

private String operation;
private String api_key;
private User user;

public void setOperation(String operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public void setApi_key(String api_key) {
    this.api_key = "123";
}
```

}

**RegisterFragment.java**

```
private void registerProcess(String name, String email,String password){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    //user.setApi_key(api_key);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
    request.setApi_key(Constants.KEY);
    request.setUser(user);
    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed");
            Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}
```

**Constants.java**

```
public class Constants {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://wangjian.site90.net/";
//public static final String BASE_URL = "http://bravonet.my/ct2/api/";
public static final String REGISTER_OPERATION = "register";
public static final String KEY = "api_key";
public static final String LOGIN_OPERATION = "login";
public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD_OPERATION = "chgPass";

public static final String SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String FAILURE = "failure";
public static final String IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";

public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String UNIQUE_ID = "unique_id";

public static final String TAG = "Learn2Crack";
```

}

The code above i just modify from **learn2crack** original code link to [Android Login Registration System with PHP and MySQL (Updated) – Server #1](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/04/android-login-registration-php-mysql-server.html/2)

**I'm a really newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. thanks so much!**

There are my **RequestInterface.java**

```
public interface RequestInterface {

@POST("learn2crack-login-register/")
//@POST("user/")
//@POST("android/login_registration/")
Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
```

}

Comment: why don't you try it? your code looks good, just don't forget to fix this `this.api_key = "123";` in `setApi_key()` change it to `this.api_key = api_key ;`

Comment: my partner let me set api_key as '123'. i got error like "use jsonreader.setlenient(true) to accept malformed json at line 1 column 1 path $"

Comment: please update question to append source-code of `requestInterface.operation()`, also if you can Log the `requset` object as json string

Comment: ok good, now add this `.setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)` before `.build()` this will log request and response content, get the JSON sent in the request and check if it has an issue (good to add it to the question too)

Comment: There are have error that cannot resolved setLogLevel and LogLevel.